# datatables javascript list with laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables

i am trying to transfer data from laravel to datatables. but in no way is the incoming data datatables loaded. where is the mistake?
Laravel function and javascript are specified below.
I have stated the result of the incoming data console below.

```
public function getTag()
    {
        $tag = Tag::all();
        $data['data'] = $tag;
        return $data;
}
```

```
async created() {
        const res = await this.callApi('get', 'app/get_tags')
        if (res.status === 200) {
            console.log(res.data);
            $("#datatables").DataTable({
                data: res.data,
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "tagName",
                    },
                ]
            });
        } else {
            console.log("error database");
        }
    }
```

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "tagName": "asdasdasd",
            "created_at": "2021-08-14T13:44:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-08-14T13:44:00.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "tagName": "asdasd",
            "created_at": "2021-08-14T13:45:03.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-08-14T13:45:03.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "tagName": "asdasd23",
            "created_at": "2021-08-14T13:45:26.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-08-14T13:45:26.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "tagName": "asdasd23231",
            "created_at": "2021-08-14T13:46:17.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-08-14T13:46:17.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, it shows that the results of `console.log(res.data)` is an object structured as `{ "data": [ ... ] }`. In that case I think you need to change your DataTable `data` option from `data: res.data` to `data: res.data.data`. Reason: It _appears_ that you have an extra level of nesting in your overall response payload structure - and the DataTables `data` option needs to point to the location of the row `[ ... ]` array, for DataTables to iterate over that array. This is something of a guess - hence my comment, and not an answer.